# in mobile devices, white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; kinda do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap, and when the screen gets xs, the effect of `white-space:nowrap;     overflow:hidden;     text-overflow:ellipsis;`  aren't working. when the screen gets big, I want the long texts to have `white-space:nowrap;     overflow:hidden;     text-overflow:ellipsis;` but they still keep going.

sorry if that's not clear. In my web, users can post anything. and the title is being displayed. if the title is too long, they get cut off with `white-space:nowrap;     overflow:hidden;     text-overflow:ellipsis;`
but when screen gets smaller the length of the title remain still so they ruin the structure of table.

So I want the title to have an effect of `white-space:nowrap;     overflow:hidden;     text-overflow:ellipsis;` when the screen size decreases.

how do I achieve this?

Comment: you have to define the `@media` query check this for effecting the specific size css elements http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: @JohnAnkanna media (min-width: screen-sm-min) {white-space:nowrap;     overflow:hidden;     text-overflow:ellipsis; when the screen size decreases.}?

Comment: @JohnAnkanna not working...

Comment: `/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */`
`@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }`

Comment: @mikebraa Please create a working example (https://jsfiddle.net/) for your problem, it will help us to give you a better solution which is not based on gussing

Comment: @AlonEitan so when screen gets smaller, is there a way to differ length for white-space:nowrap;     overflow:hidden;     text-overflow:ellipsis;?

Comment: @JohnAnkanna so when screen gets smaller, is there a way to differ length for white-space:nowrap;     overflow:hidden;     text-overflow:ellipsis;?

Comment: `@media (min-width:450px){white-space:nowrap} ` try like this by overriding the css

Answer (score 0):

In mobile devices, as the screen size is less than **480px**, so the elements come one below the another, so the `overflow` property may not work.

Comment: so when screen gets smaller, is there a way to differ length for white-space:nowrap;     overflow:hidden;     text-overflow:ellipsis;?